# How do I send a direct message to someone when they join a server with discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, bots, discord.py

I'm writing a bot for my discord server and I want to send an automatic direct message to anyone who joins the server for the first time. I have looked through the documentation and I can't find anything about how to do this. I am using python 3.5 and discord.py version 0.16.12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_join

You can do something along the lines of:

```
await bot.send_message(member, "hello")
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this should work if you are using the discord py rewrite
make sure you have enabled intents for the bot as shown in this picture
[image: member intents enable]

```
intents=discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix= cmd,intents=intents)
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send(f"your welcome message here")
```